# Angular - find that route that activated the application in AppComponent

Tags: angular

I have an application that will load an initial set of data in AppComponent, **unless** the app was started with a specific route.

- if it loads as `www.exmaple.com`, then I will fetch all of the
  available data from the API.
- If the app is initialized with `www.example.com/home/one-two-three`,
  then I will skip the initial data loading, and use a `resolve` to
  just get the `one-two-three` data

***Q:*** In `AppComponent` `constructor()`, or `ngOnInit()`, is there a way to find what `route` is being loaded?

I have access to the `ActivatedRoute` and `Router`, but I cannot see the URL that is beign loaded when inspecting these objects in debug mode. I want to get the initial request for all data sent as soon as possible during the initialization process - or decide to send no request if the url is for a specific component

Comment: I figured out how to do it. Filter and subscribe to Router.evetns for NavigationStart events, then use the router.parseUrl(event.url) - the resulting UrlTree can be checked for the UrlSegment's that match the path that you are looking for

Comment: You should post that as an answer and accept it. I too have this same need, so it would be nice to have an *answered* question to refer back to instead of a comment which can be deleted at any time.